# Помогите определиться, как лучше спроектировать БД в redis?

Tags: python, aiogram, redis

Делаю ТГ бота. БД юзеров бота хранится редисе в виде хеша

```
hset users:<tg_user_id> field_one key_one field_two key_two
```

В этом хеше хранится инфа об id юзера в тг, юзернейм в тг, статус оплаты, статус подписки.

Далее надо сделать, чтобы бот отправлял сообщения юзеру по расписанию на основе интересов юзера которые юзер указал боту.

Тут вопрос, как лучше сделать:

1. создавать отдельно список интересов для юзера в редисе, затем перебирать его и отправлять контент из бд если интерес есть в списке.
2. или просто добавить новые поля и значения хешу который уже создан когда юзера добавили в БД после нажатия команды /start. И уже проверять хеш на наличие полей с названием интереса и с ключом yes в нем и после отправлять сообщение.

Как думаете? Какое решение будет лучше\хуже и почему? Только учусь... много вопросов...

Answer (score 0):

Оба подхода имеют свои преимущества и недостатки, и в конечном итоге зависят от ваших конкретных потребностей и предпочтений. Основные различия между этими подходами можно рассмотреть следующим образом:

1. Создание отдельного списка интересов для каждого пользователя в Redis:

   - Преимущества:

     - Удобство: Вы можете легко получить список интересов для каждого пользователя и перебирать их для отправки соответствующего контента.
     - Гибкость: Пользователь может иметь различные интересы в разное время, и вы можете легко изменять и обновлять список интересов.
   - Недостатки:

     - Дополнительная сложность кода: Вам нужно будет обрабатывать отдельный список интересов для каждого пользователя и проверять его на наличие совпадений с контентом, который вы хотите отправить.
     - Увеличение размера базы данных: Если у вас есть большое количество пользователей и каждый имеет свой собственный список интересов, это может привести к увеличению размера базы данных Redis.
2. Добавление новых полей и значений в существующий хеш пользователя:

   - Преимущества:

     - Простота кода: Вам не нужно обращаться к отдельному списку интересов для каждого пользователя, так как информация об интересах уже содержится в существующем хеше пользователя.
     - Более эффективное использование памяти: Поскольку информация об интересах хранится в том же хеше, что и другая информация о пользователе, это может уменьшить занимаемое место в базе данных.
   - Недостатки:

     - Ограничение на количество интересов: Если у вас есть ограниченное количество полей в хеше пользователя и вы хотите хранить большое количество интересов для каждого пользователя, это может стать проблемой. В этом случае вам может потребоваться пересматривать структуру вашей базы данных.

В конечном итоге, выбор между этими подходами зависит от ваших предпочтений и требований проекта. В целом, рекомендуется -  проанализировать ожидаемый объем данных, количество пользователей и структуру вашей базы данных, чтобы принять более информированное решение.

А ещё, присмотритесь к другим системам кэша, например [Dragonfly](https://www.dragonflydb.io/). Как показала практика на моей работе - весьма неплохая система. И полностью совместима с редис клиентами)

Comment: Cпасибо. Рассматриваю еще 1 вариант и скорее буду делать его. 1 - На входе после того как юзер нажал на кнопку /start добавлять имя его хеша во множество subscribed_users. 2 - При рассылке получать из редис моножество ключей (которые будут идентичны именам хешей юзеров). 3 - в цикле перебирать элементы множеств и заходить в хеш юзера... а далее уже в хеше брать поле интереса и по нему отправлять контент. Мне кажется так еще меньше кода и достаточно гибко. Как только юзер отписался - просто удалять его из множества. Что думаете?

Comment: думаю что вместо использования кеша, в вашем случае было бы удобнее взять какую-нибудь субд - например postgresql. Построить модели, связи и прочее. Доступ к нужным данным будет удобнее, без циклов с переборами и прочего :)